# Can I search through all the commits by my "github team"?

Tags: github

I want to search through all the PRs/Commits that my https://github.com/orgs/ORG/teams/TEAM has made across all the PRs?

Is this possible? Currently, I am using labels to search through them.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a real working link?